# Google Polyline algorithm license

Tags: open-source, licensing, mapping

Does anyone know if the [Google polyline algorithm](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/polylinealgorithm.html) has a license attached to it? I would like to use the algorithm in a different mapping solution I am developing but I'm unsure of it's restrictions. There doesn't appear to be any info on the algorithm description page.

Comment: Have you tried checking for a patent? Have you tried emailing Google?

Comment: I can't find an email address but I have posted a question on their forum and got no reply. http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=48206bb26c87dfad&hl=en

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but here is my understanding:

1. Algorithms don't have licenses, source code has licenses. If you write your own code then that is fine.
2. Algorithms are like mathematical truths so cannot be patented. Patent attorneys try and get around this by patenting the concept of "the algorithm implemented in software". If the algorithm has been patented  like this then you'll need to ask a lawyer, and it will depend on where you live and your code runs.
3. This is why we should be against software patents :-)
4. Looking at the Google page you should be fine (but I'm not a lawyer). The algorithm looks like they have designed it for others to use.

Comment: So lets say if I implement the GIF compression algorithm (lzw) myself then I can override the Unisys patent (which is expired by now, but lets say it 1999)... nope sorry still need to pay them.

Comment: I have to admit I haven't read the Unisys patent, but I suspect that if it is like most software patents if you implemented it using wooden cogs and bits of string then you wouldn't. As I said point 2, usually the patent is on "the algorithm in software", but it varies eg between Europe and the US.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_patent_debate in the "Ideas are not patentable" for more information.